# WordPress menu>Custom Link: removing my link formatting and adding %20

Tags: menus, formatting

I am pasting this url:

```
<a href="#" id="event_inquiryToggle">TEST</a>
```

into WordPress Custom Link menu item. When I hit save it saves it as such:

```
http://a%20href=#%20id=event_inquiryToggleTEST/a
```

As such it breaks the link.

Thoughts on what I need to add to WP to remove such functionality without having to use a third party plugin?

Answer (score 1):

That is perfectly fine behaviour of WordPress. You can´t just paste markup in the href field, the input gets sanitized.

Use the built-in functionality to provide special links with classes if you want a different styling. See the attached image for those fields.

You will have to activate those options through the options tab at the top of the page, though.

[image: Edit menu entry]

Comment: thanks m8. much appreciated. i thought "get sanitized" shouldn't be used any longer as a term?

Comment: Why not? For me that´s common technical language.